# Extra output from my Php JSON

Tags: php, json

I've been learning Php/SQL/JSON for just over 24 hours now and its gone pretty well. I've made a DB, have php page now to add data to the DB.

I made a php page to return a JSON object. And it does do that, but It returns some text also it seems.

```
[{"id":"5","udid":"4564645","name":"LastName","score":"999999.00","date":"2011-04-14 18:10:33"},{"id":"4","udid":"9123456789012345678901234567590123456789","name":"sdfdsf","score":"111110.13","date":"2011-04-14 18:10:01"},{"id":"3","udid":"0123456789012345678901234567890123456789","name":"derktreb","score":"710.13","date":"2011-04-14 18:09:12"},{"id":"1","udid":"0123456789012345678901234567890123456789","name":"brandontreb","score":"210.13","date":"2011-04-14 11:40:05"},{"id":"2","udid":"0123456789012345678901234567890123456789","name":"brandontreb","score":"210.13","date":"2011-04-14 18:08:35"}]
Name    Score
```

[EDIT] 'Name' 'Score' are no longer appearing. Was an old version of this php file being called that was causing it to appear. The code below *seems* to be working ok. See any problems in it?

If you see any noob mistakes I've made please point them out to me.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
// get_scores.php
/** MySQL database name */
define('DB_NAME', 'b_Chat');
/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'b_App');
/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'testtesttest');
/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', $_ENV{DATABASE_SERVER});

$table = "highscores";

// Initialization
$conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $conn);

// Error checking
if(!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect ' . mysql_error());
}

$type   = isset($_GET['type']) ? $_GET['type'] : "global";
$offset = isset($_GET['offset']) ? $_GET['offset'] : "0";
$count  = isset($_GET['count']) ? $_GET['count'] : "10";
$sort   = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : "score DESC";

// Localize the GET variables
$udid  = isset($_GET['udid']) ? $_GET['udid'] : "";
$name  = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name']  : "";

// Protect against sql injections
$type   = mysql_real_escape_string($type);
$offset = mysql_real_escape_string($offset);
$count  = mysql_real_escape_string($count);
$sort   = mysql_real_escape_string($sort);
$udid   = mysql_real_escape_string($udid);
$name   = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

// Build the sql query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE ";

switch($type) {
    case "global":
        $sql .= "1 ";
        break;
    case "device":
        $sql .= "udid = '$udid' ";
        break;
    case "name":
        $sql .= "name = '$name' ";
        break;
}

$sql .= "ORDER BY $sort ";
$sql .= "LIMIT $offset,$count ";

$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);

if(!$result) {
    die("Error retrieving scores " . mysql_error());
}
//echo $result;
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Many Thanks,
-Code

Comment: Weird. The words are outside the JSON encoded result. Those *must* come from elsewhere. Is this the full code? You are 100% sure? This is not used in an include somewehre?

Comment: What happens if you just don't echo the json. Do those artifacts remain?

Comment: @diEcho the string "Name  Score" underneath the JSON output

Comment: Server wasnt letting me overwrite the old php file with the new one I uploaded so the output was from a previous file. Soon as i deleted it and uploaded the code shown above it worked ok. Is everything else in that Php code looking ok? Anything that should be done so its better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one optimization

instead of this

```
// Protect against sql injections
$type   = mysql_real_escape_string($type);
$offset = mysql_real_escape_string($offset);
$count  = mysql_real_escape_string($count);
$sort   = mysql_real_escape_string($sort);
$udid   = mysql_real_escape_string($udid);
$name   = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

try shorthand ( first handle mysql injection with `$_GET`)

$get_data = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string',$_GET);
```

**Note:** `$_GET` should not be multidimensional array

also change the order

```
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($conn);
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

it appears to be that something else is executing AFTER this snippet...

try adding exit(); after the mysql_close() and see what happens. If you get the result you are expecting then its a definite that your request is also executing other code too.

Comment: See commment above ToonMariner, Thanks -Code